# I want to add script in recat js when i run command then automatically following things are happen

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, automation

1. deltetion of package-lock.json file
2. deltetion of node module from current app
3. installing all depandancy which is present in package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the answer using the file system module we can delete the node_module folder and package-lock.json file and with help of the child processor we can run the command npm i.
also when we add command in package.json file  inside of that also we can  run npm install after completing of delete the folder and file